# Elasticsearch Update by Query - Performance is very slow

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch

We are using flat documents arch. For e.g We have GrandFather, Father and Son/Daughter. So all properties of GrandFather will be there in Father document and all Father's properties will be in the Son's document and Daughter's document.

When we want to update something for Father then we are using /_update_by_query with condition as where fatherId=ABC update these properties.

We are passing few of these properties along with /_update_by_query

```
slices=1&requests_per_second=-1&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&refresh=true&wait_for_completion=true&timeout=1m
```

Now update by query similiar like this during load takes more than 30 seconds and sometimes 1 second. But as of now this is becoming bottleneck for our message processing.

Do you have any suggestion how can be improve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the Observations that can help you.

If the number of documents to be updated is very large then query performance might be on slower side, so you need to verify for queries taking longer time if large number of records are being updated.

From the ES documentation

> While processing an update by query request, Elasticsearch performs multiple search requests sequentially to find all of the matching documents. A bulk update request is performed for each batch of matching documents. Any query or update failures cause the update by query request to fail and the failures are shown in the response. Any update requests that completed successfully still stick, they are not rolled back.

Also **slices** parameter can be tweaked or just let ES decide the slicing param on its own, again from the official documentation

> Setting slices to auto chooses a reasonable number for most data streams and indices. If you’re slicing manually or otherwise tuning automatic slicing, keep in mind that:
> Query performance is most efficient when the number of slices is equal
> to the number of shards in the index or backing index. If that number
> is large (for example, 500), choose a lower number as too many slices
> hurts performance.
>
> Setting slices higher than the number of shards
> generally does not improve efficiency and adds overhead.
>
> Update performance scales linearly across available resources with the number
> of slices.

so you can try setting the **slice** paramter to **auto** and then check the performance.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!